# capturing page unload javascript

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload, onunload

I have a web application which makes file uploads. While users are uploading, they need to stay on the page so download can continue, and if they want to leave the page I give them a confirmation box asking if are they sure about leaving the page. With the following little script:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return "You have active uplaods, they won't be committed if you leave now!";
}
```

So it's supposed to reload the page or navigate somewhere else when it gets the confirmation from the user, but instead it stalls till the upload is done after user clicks "*leave this page*" button. I can abort the upload process only if I can detect the click on "*leave this page*", but I can't.

I've checked the event `window.onunload` too but it fires right at the time that browser is actually navigating to the next page(unfortunately after the upload finishes:/).

I need to be able to refresh or navigate as soon as user clicks "*leave this page*". Is there any way to get the "*leave this page*" command? Or is there any workaround to this?

Comment: I use blueimp jquery file upload widget for upload.

Comment: This piece of code is not correct : it's `window` without s, and it's `return "You have...` without the equal

Comment: haha :D yeah they are typos, I should have copied and pasted :)